# Equivalent iteration for 2D and 3D array flattened as 1D array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following code for 2D dimensional arrays being flattened as 1D C-style arrays:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int width = 4, height = 4;

    int arr[width * height];

    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            arr[i * width + j] = k++;
        }
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            int* ptr = &arr[0] + height * i; //perfect also works with &arr[0] + width * i;
            std::cout<<ptr[j]<<"   ";
        }
    }
}
```

It prints: `0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14   15`
as demonstrated here: http://ideone.com/gcgocu
The array does NOT have to be a square (4x4) and the above still works.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with a 3D array so I did:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int width = 4, height = 4, depth = 4;

    int arr[width * height * depth];

    for (int i = 0, l = 0; i < depth; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < width; ++k)
            {
                arr[k + width * (j + depth * i)] = l++; //works just fine. perfect.
            }
        }
    }

    //Fails below.. Run-time access violation error.

    for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < width; ++k)
            {
                int** ptr = reinterpret_cast<int**>(&arr[0] + width * (j + depth * i)); //this can't be right.
                std::cout<<ptr[j][k]; //this line should stay the same.
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It fails as demonstrated here: http://ideone.com/yqY2oK

How can I do the same thing for a 3D array?

Comment: My advice is never do that.

Comment: Why? For both 2D and 3D or just not do it for 3D?

Comment: For all 2D and 3D....nD.

Comment: But it is perfectly valid to map a 2D array onto a 1D array.. I only have a problem mapping a 3D onto a 1D or 2D.

Comment: In fact by doing this you are cheating your compiler. Old saying: *Cheating is not a problem but if it being caught, then it is a problem* (I forgot the exact sentence). Sometimes you may get some unexpected result.

Comment: And you can't use nested arrays because...?

Comment: I just wanted to know if I could do it. I wasn't actually planning on using it in production code. It was the algorithm I wanted to figure out.

Comment: Note that your indexing is wrong with different size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should works:

```
for (int i = 0, l = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < width; ++k) {
            arr[k + width * (j + height * i)] = l++; // Index fixed
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
    int (&ptr)[height][width] = *reinterpret_cast<int (*)[height][width]>(&arr[0] + width * height * i);
    for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < width; ++k) {
            std::cout << ptr[j][k] << " "; //this line should stay the same.
        }
    }
}
```

whereas in the 2D snippet:

```
int (&ptr)[width] = *reinterpret_cast<int (*)[width]>(&arr[0] + width * i);
```

Comment: I take it there is no way to convert `ptr` to `int***` right? If not, that's ok, I like this solution still.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: `int arr[depth][height][width]` and `int arr[depth * height * width]` are flat continuous sequences of `int` (without extra pointer). `int***` involves pointers and is not a flat array of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`int**` cast takes your 1-d array and makes it an array of *pointers*.  It does not map your values to a flat array.

You can use `boost::multi_array` to do what you want.